# Apple Mail not working properly

Tags: macos, email, catalina

Since installing Catalina on both my laptop and desktop I can only receive emails on the laptop - what do I have to do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Apple Mail has a wonderful connection doctor.

I would open it and see what specific error it finds and then work to solve it from the wizard steps and help that the connection doctor provides for your specific setup and mail provider.

Once you've done that or if you can't solve it - then you can ask a follow on question or reach out to that mail vendor's support with a very specific error condition and not just "mail doesn't work"

1. Click the Window menu
2. Click the Connection Doctor item
3. Follow the results for any light that's not green

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's because of using POP3 as incoming mail server, switch to IMAP to insure that the message will arrive to all of your devices not just a single device.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31406911/8811160).

> POP3 and IMAP are two different protocols (methods) used to access
>   email.
>
> Of the two, IMAP is the better options and the recommended option when
>   you need to check your emails from multiple devices, such as a work
>   laptop, a home computer, or a tablet, smartphone, or other mobile
>   device. Tap into your synced (updated) account from any device with
>   IMAP.
>
> POP3 downloads email from a server to a single computer, then deletes
>   it from the server. Because your messages get downloaded to a single
>   computer or device and then deleted from the server, it can appear
>   that mail is missing or disappearing from your Inbox if you try to
>   check your mail from a different computer.

Comment: Forgot to mention you can change the incoming mail server configurations from within mail app preferences, to know which server to use refer to your mail provider.

Comment: Welcome to Apple.SE @Saud !  you can [edit] the answer to update it. In case you haven't already, take the quick [tour] to out site too!

Comment: @ankii Thanks for the warm welcome, I know that already but I didn't edit the answer because I wanted it to be general (for all mail clients) rather than specific to the exact question.